# How to write Criteria Query that checks for multiple values in same column along with other WHERE conditions?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

Please convert the following SQL Query to a Criteria Query---------
I have the following table PEOPLE-

| ID | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | A |
| 2 | Harry | B |
| 3 | Tom | C |
| 4 | John | A |
| 5 | Sally | C |
| 6 | Tom | B |
| 7 | Tom | D |

**The query must return the list of records that satisfies the conditions- Name='Tom' AND Code='A' or 'B' or 'C'**
----In this Case only two records-----

| ID | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | A |
| 3 | Tom | C |
| 6 | Tom | B |

The SQL query will be something like this----

```
Select * from PEOPLE
where   NAME='TOM' and CODE in ('A' ,'B','C') ;
```

How do I convert this SQL query to a CriteriaQuery?

I could write the the criteriaQuery till the 1st where condition--

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(People.class);
         cr.add(Restrictions.eq("name","Tom"));
```

Comment: Try pr restriction `Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("CODE", "A"),(Restrictions.eq("CODE", "B"));`

Comment: If possible please give the solution for the same but using 'NOT IN' instead of 'IN'--

Comment: For not in :  `Restrictions.and(Restrictions.ne("CODE", "A"),(Restrictions.ne("CODE", "B"));`

Comment: The fix is throwing error when I am adding more than 2 restrictions in OR. I have updated my questions description. Can you please go through it once again

Comment: check the code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
ArrayList<String> values= new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");

//Your creteria
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(People.class);

//Array of conditions
List<Criterion> conditions = new ArrayList<Criterion>();

Criterion nameCr= Restrictions.eq("name", "Tom"); 
conditions.add(nameCr);

Criterion codeCr =Restrictions.in("code", values) ;
conditions.add(codeCr);


Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();

for (Criterion criterion : conditions) {
conjunction.add(criterion);
}

cr.add(conjunction);
```